# How properties are applied to nested element (of html) in css?

Tags: html, css

see the following code

```
<div>
    <!--some code-->
       <div id="inner">
           <!--this is div in div-->
       </div>
</div>
```

and suppose in a css code linked to this we have set font-family to "stencil" of outer div does this means that if for inner div we don't set font-family to any value then it is also going to be "stencil" due to the outer div?

Comment: It depends on the element and the property. In this case, yes, "stencil" will be applied to the child `div` elements. For more info on inheritance, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance

Comment: The title is *far* more general than the body of the question. Which one is this about? The specific question is almost trivial, the general question would have an essay-long answer (when answered properly).

Answer (score 0):

yes, you are right with your guess. if a certain attribute is not found for an element, the parents value is used. first, an element uses the parents' attributes, then "updates" with its own style-attribute and then "updates" these attributes with the value of "style='css-here'", so the style-attribute is most important when it comes to style, then the own css is checked and after that the parents values are used (if neccessary).
This "inheritance-tree" (parents, css, style-attribute) does not apply to all attributes, for font-family it definitely works, but there are surely some exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If the inner div has `font-family: inherit;` (which is the default for `font-family` on `div` elements for every browser that supports CSS I can think of), then yes.

Comment: No, browsers have *no* default value for `font-family` on `div` elements. And this implies that inheritance takes place when no style sheet sets the property. The point is that this does not even depend on support to the `inherit` value in a browser.